# How to Modify this Branch in ARM64?

Tags: disassembly, arm

I try to modify the branch of this disassembly in a binary:

```
SUB             SP, SP, #0x60
STP             X26, X25, [SP,#0x50+var_40]
STP             X24, X23, [SP,#0x50+var_30]
STP             X22, X21, [SP,#0x50+var_20]
STP             X20, X19, [SP,#0x50+var_10]
STP             X29, X30, [SP,#0x50+var_s0]
ADD             X29, SP, #0x50
MOV             X20, X0
MOV             X0, X2
BL              _objc_retain
MOV             X19, X0
ADRP            X8, #selRef_shouldCheckForUpdate@PAGE
LDR             X1, [X8,#selRef_shouldCheckForUpdate@PAGEOFF] ; char *
MOV             X0, X20 ; void *
BL              _objc_msgSend
CBZ             W0, loc_ADCC
```

Basically, the binary are checking for update and will prompt if it should, and for the sake of learning, I wanted to achieve on how to:

1. Always go to loc_ADCC and;
2. Always ignore loc_ADCC (Skip from going to loc_ADCC)

This ARM64 really got me confused, I could however understand it in 32bit, but not in 64bit. It's like a new world. You could see the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmibr.jpg) for a better visualization.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does "Always ignore loc_ADCC" mean?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky I suppose it implies "always skip branching to loc_ADCC" (and the compare before it I think)

Comment: You're right @ElianKamal

Comment: Just for reference: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cjaghefc.html - CBZ and CBNZ definition. Just NOP it out (put NOP(s) of the same size instead of it) to avoid jump.

Comment: by the way, thank you for putting disassembly as text and not just a screenshot! I hope those who downvoted the question leave a comment why they did it so it can be improved.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky It's always my practice to type it out as to ease commenter's job when answering. I think it got downvoted because this question somehow looks stupid, but hey I got to start somewhere :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, there are these  options:

1. to always take the branch, you need to convert `CBZ` (compare and branch if zero) to simple `B` (branch always). Let's have a look at the encodings of both:

[B:](https://developer.arm.com/products/architecture/a-profile/docs/ddi0596/latest/a64-base-instructions-alphabetic-order/b)

    `31 30  29  28  27  26   25 .. 0
     0  0  0   1   0   1    imm26`

[CBZ:](https://developer.arm.com/products/architecture/a-profile/docs/ddi0596/latest/a64-base-instructions-alphabetic-order/cbz)

`31  30  29  28  27  26  25  24  23..5 4..0
sf  0   1   1   0   1   0   0   imm19 Rt`

To convert `CBZ` to `B`, you need to patch the opcode part (bits 31..26) and move the `imm19` field (branch offset) to the `imm26` field of the `B` opcode (bits 25..0). Since both opcodes interpret the offset in the same way (multiply by 4 and add to PC), you don't need to do any conversion besides sign extension.

For example, let's take this instruction from a random sample I had:

```
05088 E0 01 00 34  CBZ W0, loc_50C4
```

Opcode as a 32-bit value: `0x340001E0` (AArch64 always uses little-endian instructions)

In binary: `00110100000000000000000111100000`.

Split by fields:

`0  0110100 0000000000000001111 00000
sf op     imm19               Rt`

Let's assemble the `B` opcode (sign-extending imm19 to 26 bits):

`000101  00000000000000000000001111
op      imm26`

Or, as hex: 0x1400000F

After patching:

```
5088 0F 00 00 14                 B               loc_50C4
```

2. To skip the branch, you can patch `CBZ` to a `NOP` (no operation). The `NOP` encoding for ARM64 is 0xD503201F or [`1F 20 03 D5`](https://developer.arm.com/products/architecture/a-profile/docs/ddi0596/latest/a64-base-instructions-alphabetic-order/nop)

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer! It helps a lot! If you don't mind, I would like to read more about the explanation you did in 'Split by fields and assemble' section, could you point me a good learning head-start (basically how you split it and sign-extending)? :)