# How to Modify CBZ Branch in ARM64?

Tags: ida, assembly, android, arm, patching

[image: ARM64 assembly screenshot]

If I want after running the **`CBZ W0, loc_C5C8`** command
Run to the **`ADRP X8,#selRef_curent_version@PAGE`** command 
regardless of the condition (in picture), what should I do?

Comment: Your image is not really well done, since it shows the graphical few instead of the flat one. It's not clear if you need `B` (unconditional branch) or `NOP` (no operation) to simply replace the `CBZ`.

Answer (score 1):

CBZ is a compare and branch if zero.

It does not affect flags, which means that the compare part has no effect other than branching or not.

You can simply patch the `CBZ` into a `B` instruction.

Comment: More information in this answer:
https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18839/how-to-modify-this-branch-in-arm64

Comment: Thanks for answering
I have tried your way to convert CBZ to B, but it is not a suitable branch, but I want it to work. Do you have any help for me?